# Web app receiving location updates via FCM

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are designing a system to track user location from a central portal. It will consist of

1. An API that receives user location and sends those messages to a Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) topic
2. A mobile app (react-native) that sends periodic location updates to the above API
3. a browser app (react) that subscribes to the above FCM topic

Is this a correct solution? We are in doubt mostly due to the fact that location updates will be pushed at a high-frequency (every 30 seconds from 10-100 users) and FCM messages are delivered as notifications.

Answer (score 0):

FCM latency is quite low, especially when you send directly to ID tokens (so not using topics). The message volume you mention is not a concern for the FCM infrastructure, which handles multiple billions of messages per day.

If you want a better latency guarantee you could consider using the Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore, but:

1. Those messages will typically only be delivered while the app is active.
2. It means you'll need to send messages through both the database (in case the app is active), and FCM (in case the app isn't active).

Comment: Thanks @Frank my concern was mainly because FCM might throttle messages per project. What about FCM messages being delivered as notifications? Will the browser app show a popup everytime a location update push message is received? Can the app capture the message and update a map instead of displaying as a nofication?